# In Rails's new javascript called Stumulus, whas is the point of the hasClass logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

The logic in the js for `this.has[LogicalName]Class` is always true, as the class is always defined.

For example if you have the html:

`<div class="someclass" data-controller=​"example"​ data-example-hidden-class=​"hidden"​>`

And then the js magic property:

`hasHiddenClass: boolean`

The boolean `this.hasHiddenClass` is always `true`.

My question is - what is the case where this would ever be false? I cannot see it ever being false.

Here is the docs regarding this property: https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/css-classes

Answer (score 0):

If the element that that's the controller does not have the class attribute then the value will be false.

```html
div class="someclass" data-controller=​"example"​ data-example-hidden-class=​"hidden"​>
```

```js
this.hasHiddenClass; // true
```

If not set at all...

```html
div class="someclass" data-controller=​"example"​>
```

```js
this.hasHiddenClass; // false
```

This is useful to default to some other behaviour or other class if not set.

```js
if (this.hasHiddenClass) {
  // do the thing and then add hidden class
  this.element.classList.add(this.hiddenClass);
}
```